# Need to right click on command line window for jar to continue working

Tags: java, spring-boot, command-line, jar

I have to wake up a springboot application running on command line

I have a simple Spring Boot (Rest Service) application. I packaged it in a jar and I run it on Windows in a command line window by doing "java -jar .... jarname.jar". The issue is that after the application gets going for a while, as new requests come in, i need to right click on the command window running the app for it to continue working... it feels almost as if i had to wake it up... Any ideas as of why this might be? Thank you!

I expect the application to run without me having to right click on it from time to time to "wake it up"

Comment: Examples of your code would help make the question a bit more clear and answerable.

Comment: Hi Matt, thank you for the response. I do not believe code would help since the issue happens in two completely unrelated codebases. To sum it up. Imagine you have a jar running, the jar is a spring boot rest service. After a while it hangs, and you need to right click on the command prompt window that is running the jar.